# Nginx: Logging 403's from proxies

Tags: nginx, proxy, fail2ban, proxypass

So our server setup goes like this:

```
www <-> nginx <-> backend services
```

The internal services require authorisation, which often fails with a 403 if a user's token is incorrect and so forth.

Now, we also use `fail2ban` which keeps an eye on nginx's error.log files for something fishy and bans IP's for a certain amount of time.

What I'd like to achieve here is have nginx log an error when the backend services return a 403, so that if there are excess 403's `fail2ban` can ban the IP address for the next ten minutes or so. Currently, nginx doesn't log anything to the error.log file if a backend service responds with a 403.

How can that be done?
Thanks.